# Remove the content of NSURL Path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, assets

i Used the code below to save photos that taken from camera

code:

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {
    UIImage *viewImage = imageView.image;  // was taken from Camera
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
    // Request to save the image to camera roll  
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
        if (error) {  
            NSLog(@"error");  
        } else {  
            NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL); 
            self.imgUrl = assetURL;
        }  
    }];  
    [library release];
}
```

this is the Log of NSLOG

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2A72A3FF-1662-4979-8DD7-0F5721C49F81&ext=JPG
```

Now when im done with the image how to remove it ?

I tried :

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:[self.imgUrl absoluteString]  error:NULL];
```

but it didnt work 
any help will be great

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't plan to save the image to the user's Photo library permanently, why are you saving the image there initially ?

You should save the image to your application's sandbox folder and then delete it from there.

**You cannot delete images from the Photo Library**

Answer (score 2):

Try using NSURL Path. Besure to check file exist at path before deleting your filepath.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:[self.imgUrl path]  error:NULL];
```

Comment: I believe imgURL is NSURL Object, if so it should work. Just try to print it url u are getting

Comment: also i NSLog(@"%@",[self.imgUrl path]); the result is : /asset.JPG

Comment: well get the error the filemanager is reporting, instead of passing Null as the error object, and you will see that the error will report access denied... Like I said you cannot delete images from the Photo library!

Comment: Im sure removeItemAtPath requires the full path of your Image, to delete.

Comment: You can save the step of converting NSURL to a path by calling [fileManager removeItemAtURL:self.imageUrl error:NULL];